# MySite NTLM Authentication direct link

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, people-picker, mysite

I'm using SharePoint 2013. I've created two web apps :
-Sharepoint
-MySite

I extended MySite with "External" named IIS Site, and configured it with FBA (plus NTLM) because external FBA users will need to access internal users' site.

So when I'm from the inside, internal users will get SSO and will be able to share with coworkers (because it's AD and it's working).

Now, I need to create FBA Users (from the codeplex FBA SP2013 plugin), but it does not show up in people picker of internal users from their MySite ...

I created them from the MySite site settings, and it does show up in SharePoint root site (my first web app that is not used) ...

Can you help troubleshooting me please ? Because the only solution I've found would be to enable Forms Auth on the internal MySite, but it disable the SSO experience from inside...

This is why I'm asking if a link (/_windows/defaults.aspx?returnUrl=/personal/UsernameHere  does not work ...) could bring me directly to windows auth (it would be nice if it could redirect to the OneDrive directly).

I hope I'm understandable enough

Comment: did you made the changes to the central admin site as well as i think did you add the peoplepicker stuff in the default zone web.config

Comment: I applied changes to the default zone web.config but I kept Forms Auth disabled for this zone. Now I come with another strange thing : from the mysite settings (connected as system account), I can see FBA user and add them to a group ... but if connected as simple AD user, and try to share with FBA user, they dont show up in ppl picker.
I also tried to create a user profile (where ppl picker is working) but no result in mysite (user POV in share settings)

Comment: I don't get how this is working ... if I create a new user profile, and I can select my FBA user ... it should be available in all sites from people picker, no ? even if it's a MySite sites collection ...

Comment: Ok, so what if I try to enable Forms Auth, and I put this link in IE bookmark : `https://mysite.mydom/_windows/default.aspx?returnUrl=%2Fpersonnal%2FMyUserNameHere%2Fdefault.aspx` they will still get SSO even if two auth. methods are enabled (and site is trusted along with certificate) ? Am I right ?

Comment: I've just been trying my link, with 2 authent methods ... It's working ! But ONLY if I type it manually in the IE address bar. When it comes from a bookmark, it does not work ...